# AlarmManager not firing on next day

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

i have set AlarmManager for particular time and updating time when older one is fired . but problem is AlarmManager  is not firing on next date but if i change date manually then its working but if automatically changes then it not firing

```
 AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, BrSendSMS.class);
    intent.putExtra("schedulesmsid", schedulesmsid);
    int schedulelistid = -1;
    try
    {
        schedulelistid = Integer.valueOf(schedulesmsid);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, schedulelistid, intent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        alarm.cancel(pendingIntent);
        alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, scheduledtime, pendingIntent);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: How you updating the alarm time??

Comment: in my broadcast receiver i am setting new time

Comment: are You sure that  the date is valid? Another possible issue: Are You turning off the device? Alarms going be killed if the device goes off, for that You need a ON_BOOT_COMPLETED_RECEIVER..

Comment: date is valid coz if i change manually its working and device id on only

Answer (score 0):

Try to use setRepeating...

use the code below...

```
                Calendar alarmTime=Calendar.getInstance();  
                alarmTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,18);
                alarmTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
                alarmTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);          
                Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,AlarmReceiver.class);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, alarmIntent, 0);
                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                Long time = alarmTime.getTimeInMillis() + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 * 2);
                alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time,24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 * 2, pendingIntent);
```

i hope it will help for you.